# Request permissions to fetch user data AND publish to Timeline in same dialog

Tags: facebook, permissions, facebook-timeline

Has anyone figured this out yet?

**The question with more fancy details:**
You've got a Facebook application that on one side fetches and analyzes the user's data, and on the other side posts fancy posts to the user's timeline using the new OG features launched yesterday. When the user begins using your application, is it required to first show the standard dialog requesting permissions to fetch and post data to Facebook, and then in a separate dialog request permission to publish to the user's timeline? To be even more specific with my question, is it possible to combine these two dialogs into a single request?

Thanks in advance!

Edit: Guess it was easier than I first thought. Here's the new Auth dialog for all people as blind as me: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/beta/authentication/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you discovered, the new Open Auth dialogue can do multiple permissions although you should review how it handles "extended permissions" beyond email and publish_actions.

Be certain to review your application settings and specifically the auth and advanced tabs as there are new options to fill out for explaining additional permissions as well as an option to enable the new dialogue before the system-wide rollout.